# AngularJS, UI Router - Navigating to "foo/bar" goes to "foo"

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

For a particular app I've got several states defined, but I'm having trouble with two in particular.

Here's what they look like:

```
 $stateProvider.state('foo', {
        url: '/foo',
        views: {
            "main": {
                controller: 'fooController',
                controllerAs: 'ctrl',
                templateUrl: 'a.html'
            },
        }           
    }).state('bar', {
        url: '/foo/bar/:id',
        views: {
            "main": {
                controller: 'barController',
                controllerAs: 'ctrl',
                templateUrl: 'b.html'
            },
        }

    });
```

Issue: Whenever I navigate in browser directly to /foo/bar/123 the route works. However if I navigate to /foo, and then to /foo/bar/123 the state briefly loads and then navigates back to /foo.

Question: Apart from changing '/foo/bar' to be '/bar' how can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to change the URL in your 'bar' state? I believe you can just change your 'bar' state to 'foo.bar' and then make your url relative "i.e. /bar/"id"

Comment: No technical reason - it will make more sense to the user. Generally, I just want to know why this config won't work as intended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe all you are looking for is one change to your config.

```
$stateProvider.state('foo', {
        url: '/foo',
        views: {
            "main": {
                controller: 'fooController',
                controllerAs: 'ctrl',
                templateUrl: 'a.html'
            },
        }           
    }).state('foo.bar', {
        url: '/bar/:id', //This will still evaluate to /foo/bar/:id
        views: {
            "main": {
                controller: 'barController',
                controllerAs: 'ctrl',
                templateUrl: 'b.html'
            },
        }

    });
```

your url should still be `/foo/bar/:id`, but ui-router will concat them together for you because you are saying that `foo` is a parent route to `bar`.
It's likely getting confused right now because it sees two routes that use `/foo` and doesn't know which to use, so it defaults to the first one defined.

Reference:
https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing

Comment: This also loads a.html alongside b.html - and the pages are meant to be entirely different views....

Comment: could you post a jsfiddle of your situation? From what I understand, you shouldn't be able to reach both of these at the same time since they are loaded into the same view.

Comment: I ended up re-working the ui router states all around to 'understand' the notion of child states. Previously, the header/footer of the site was delivered via MVC - now it has it's own router state and the /foo/bar started to magically work. Marking as answer because the child states led me to the solution. Cheers.